# PreProcessInterceptor do not intercept some of my JAX-RS Resource services

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy, interceptor

The pom.xml :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1.GA</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

The interceptor class :

```java
@Provider
@ServerInterceptor
@SecurityPrecedence
public class AuthorizationInterceptor implements PreProcessInterceptor {
    @Override
    public ServerResponse preProcess(HttpRequest request, ResourceMethod method) throws Failure, WebApplicationException {
        // some initalizations
    }
}
```

The web service not intercepted :

```java
@Path("/poi")
@Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json", "application/octet-stream"})
@Produces({"application/json", "text/json", "application/xml"})
@Restricted
public class PoiResource extends SecureResource<Poi> {

    @Inject
    public PoiRessource(PoiDao pois) {
        super(pois);
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/ping")
    @UnRestricted
    public Response ping() {
        String date = new Date().toString();
        if (log.isInfoEnabled()) log.info(String.format("Ping %s",date));
            return Response.ok(date).build();
    }
}
```

The web service intercepted :

```java
@Path("/access")
@Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json", "application/octet-stream",  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
@Produces({"application/json", "text/json", "application/xml"})
@Restricted
public class AccessResource extends SecureResource<Access> {

    @Inject
    public AccessResource(AccessDao accessDao) {
        super(accessDao);
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/ping")
    @UnRestricted
    public Response ping() {
        String date = new Date().toString();
        if (log.isInfoEnabled()) log.info(String.format("Ping %s",date));
            return Response.ok(date).build();
    }
}
```

I get an exception when I call the ping service on PoiResource :

```
2013-05-03 18:34:09.973 [http-9080-3] ERROR c.c.a.r.p.exception.ExceptionMapper - 
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.connecthings.adtag.common.dao.PoiDao.<init>(PoiDao.java:69)
while locating com.connecthings.adtag.common.dao.PoiDao
for parameter 0 at com.connecthings.adtag.poi.rest.PoiRessource.<init>(PoiRessource.java:98)
while locating com.connecthings.adtag.poi.rest.PoiRessource

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:987) ~[guice-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.connecthings.adtag.common.inject.ConfigurableRestEasyGuiceListener$1.createResource(ConfigurableRestEasyGuiceListener.java:104) ~[common-inject-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:210) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.1.GA.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:525) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.1.GA.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:502) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.1.GA.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:119) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.1.GA.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.1.GA.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.1.GA.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.1.GA.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:263) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:178) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:91) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:62) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:118) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113) [guice-servlet-3.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) [catalina.jar:6.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:6.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233) [catalina.jar:6.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191) [catalina.jar:6.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127) [catalina.jar:6.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [catalina.jar:6.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [catalina.jar:6.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293) [catalina.jar:6.0.35]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859) [tomcat-coyote.jar:6.0.35]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602) [tomcat-coyote.jar:6.0.35]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489) [tomcat-coyote.jar:6.0.35]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679) [na:1.6.0_27]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:796) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.getDB(Mongo.java:362) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.10.1.jar:na]
    at com.google.code.morphia.DatastoreImpl.<init>(DatastoreImpl.java:77) ~[morphia-0.99.jar:na]
    at com.google.code.morphia.DatastoreImpl.<init>(DatastoreImpl.java:88) ~[morphia-0.99.jar:na]
    at com.connecthings.adtag.model.dao.UnsecureGenericDao.getDs(UnsecureGenericDao.java:74) ~[common-persistence-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.connecthings.adtag.model.dao.UnsecureGenericDao.getCollection(UnsecureGenericDao.java:112) ~[common-persistence-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.connecthings.adtag.common.dao.PoiDao.<init>(PoiDao.java:73) ~[common-dao-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.connecthings.adtag.common.dao.PoiDao$$FastClassByGuice$$3bbdc31e.newInstance(<generated>) ~[guice-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastConstructor.newInstance(FastConstructor.java:40) ~[guice-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:60) ~[guice-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85) ~[guice-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254) ~[guice-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38) ~[guice-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62) ~[guice-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:84) ~[guice-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254) ~[guice-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:978) ~[guice-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1024) ~[guice-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:974) ~[guice-3.0.jar:na]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
```

I can't find out why the ping method of AccessResource is intercepted and the ping method of PoiResource is not...
The exception is thrown because the poi dao need an object initialized in the interceptor method for the instanciation.

If anybody has some clue for me, it would help a lot.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exception suggest that the issue come from the constructor of PoiDao that prevent the PoiResource to get build.

In resteasy the interceptor method is called after the resource instanciation and before resource method call.

As your resource fail to instanciate, thus the interceptor is never called.

Comment: I believed that the instanciation of the daos occured after the interception, and the contructor of PoiDao was depending on an object initialized in the interceptor. I modified the constructor of PoiDao, as you suggest, to make him independent, it works better now. Thank you!